# How to remove characters when input not matches regex in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

```
<input id="myInput" onblur="myFunction()">

<script>
    function myFunction() {
      var value= document.getElementById('myInput').value;
      var regexCharacter = /[0-9|,]+/g;
      strFirst = value.replace(regexCharacter, '')
      document.getElementById('myInput').value = strFirst
    }
</script>
```

I want to replace '' when the input does not match the regex's.
My regex just allow input number and comma.
My function is replace when input matching, i want to replace when it's not matching.
E.g a12,b2a => 12,2
can anyone help me, thanks.

Comment: Well is `12,b2a` an allowed input, given that it contains letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your function is not called to check the value with reqex.
then yout reqex replace "" when is number not charactors

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput">
```

```js
<script>
    myInput.addEventListener("input", function (e) {
      var value= document.getElementById('myInput').value;
      strFirst = value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*?)\..*/g, '$1')
      document.getElementById('myInput').value = strFirst
    });
</script>
```

in this code you can write number whith dot
whith this reqex

> value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(..*?)..*/g

Answer (score 1):

Use `/[^0-9|,]+/g` as your regex. The `^` mark is used to match any character  that's not in range.

**Pro tip:** You dont have to memorize all these tokens, just use a tool like https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should edit your regex to match letters instead of numbers. Like this: `/[a-zA-Z|]+/g`

Comment: i think so that but if you ented another languege, it's not woking. E.g Korean

Comment: Sorry, I didn't take that into account. The answer with the ^ mark should do the trick then.